# Get the greatest number of the products

Tags: mysql, sql

### The goal

I want to make a ranking and I need to get the 10 firsts of a column.

### The problem

There's the following table within my application:

```
+------+---------+
| User | Product |
+------+---------+
| 1    | 1       |
+------+---------+
| 2    | 1       |
+------+---------+
| 3    | 1       |
+------+---------+
| 4    | 1       |
+------+---------+
| 5    | 2       |
+------+---------+
| 6    | 2       |
+------+---------+
| 7    | 2       |
+------+---------+
| 8    | 3       |
+------+---------+
| 9    | 3       |
+------+---------+
```

And I want to make a ranking following this pattern:

```
+---------+----------+
| Product | Quantity |
+---------+----------+
| 1       | 4        |
+---------+----------+
| 2       | 3        |
+---------+----------+
| 3       | 2        |
+---------+----------+
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this:

```
SELECT product, COUNT(product)
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY product
ORDER BY COUNT(product) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it.

```
SELECT TOP 10 Product, COUNT(*)
FROM Table
GROUP BY Product
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Comment: `TOP` is specific to Microsoft SQL Server (and maybe Sybase).  The OP tagged the question with *mysql*.